# Define lambda authorizer response format using serverless framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

According [to this AWS documentation page](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-iam-and-lambda-authorizers-for-amazon-api-gateway-http-apis/) covering authorizers for AWS API Gateway it is possible to define authorizer as lambda function returning a boolean value in `isAuthorized` response field to allow/deny the API request.

However after numerous attempts I can't understand how to define it in `serverless.yml` (or at least in AWS console)

I'm new to AWS and serverless framework. I've decided not to dive into `IAM` access policies or `Cognito` just yet, thus I'm trying to build a very simple lambda authorizer function that just yields a boolean value to allow/deny API access.

I have defined my `functions` section in `serverless.yml` as follows:

```
functions:
  add_content:
    handler: src.handler.add
    module: src/handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: /content
          method: post
          authorizer: customAuthorizer
  customAuthorizer:
    handler: src.authorizer.authorize
    module: src/authorizer
```

The authorizer function is as simple as:

```
def authorize(event, context):
    response = {"isAuthorized": True}
    return response
```

However if I try to test it I see the following `CloudWatch` stacktrace:

```
Mon May 03 20:06:11 UTC 2021 : Endpoint request body after transformations: {"type":"TOKEN","methodArn":"arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1:238758647165:ww9wzq8hp8/ESTestInvoke-stage/GET/","authorizationToken":"123456789"}
Mon May 03 20:06:11 UTC 2021 : Sending request to https://lambda.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:238758647165:function:sls-playground-dev-customAuthorizer/invocations
Mon May 03 20:06:11 UTC 2021 : Authorizer result body before parsing: {"isAuthorized": true}
Mon May 03 20:06:11 UTC 2021 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Invalid JSON in response: Unrecognized field "isAuthorized" , not marked as ignorable
Mon May 03 20:06:11 UTC 2021 : AuthorizerConfigurationException
```

In addition to that:

1. When opening API gateway in AWS console I don't have the `Develop` section as shown in documentation.
2. If I try to create an auhtorizer manually from AWS console there's no `response mode` section.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for how to add the authorizer to the API Gateway? How to define the function? Any additional information you add would be helpful. What have you tried?

Comment: @JasonWadsworth Thanks for your patience. I have updated the question to provide a little bit more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible problems.

1. The response is incorrect for a custom authorizer for a REST API (which is what the `http` `event` is in serverless). [Output from an Amazon API Gateway Lambda authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-output.html) shows what the output should look like, as well as what is required.
2. You intended to use an HTTP API. In that case you should change the `event` to `httpApi`: [Announcing Support for AWS HTTP APIs](https://www.serverless.com/blog/aws-http-api-support)

Comment: With all due respect I doubt correctness of this answer. The documentation url that is linked to the original question contains response examples that don’t contain policy.

Comment: I think the link you have is for HTTP APIs. The `http` event in serverless is a REST API. You can use `httpApi` if you need the newer HTTP API. I'll update the answer to reflect that as an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Enable simple responses.

```
authorizer:
    payloadVersion: 2.0
    enableSimpleResponses: true
```

Handler should do a callback instead of returning the value.

```
def authorize(event, context, callback):
    response = {"isAuthorized": True}
    callback(null, response)
```

Answer (score 0):

SLS documents this [here](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/http-api)

You can set properties for your Authorizer response format like this:

```
authorizer:
    payloadVersion: 2.0
    enableSimpleResponses: true
```

This will allow `isAuthorized:true|false` responses